# removeChild used incorrectly?

Tags: actionscript, removechild

I'm just trying to remove a movie clip from the stage upon double clicking

```
package  {
    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.events.MouseEvent;
    import fl.motion.MotionEvent;

    public class Main extends MovieClip{

        var thingeh:Things;

        public function Main() {
            thingeh = new Things;
            stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onClick);
            stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.DOUBLE_CLICK, onDouble);

        }

        public function onClick(event:MouseEvent)
        {
            addChild(thingeh);

        }
        public function onDouble(event:MouseEvent)
        {
            if(thingeh)
            removeChild(thingeh);

        }
    }

}
```

Comment: At first glace, I could not find anything wrong with removeChild. What is the error you get. You should removeEventListener when removeChild is done or have weak event listener.

Comment: I have found issues with using MouseEvent.DOUBLE_CLICK test it out with another event like MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public function onDouble(event:MouseEvent)
{
    if( thingeh && contains(thingeh) )
    {
        removeChild(thingeh);
    }
}
```

Also, You may want `doubleClickEnabled = true` within your constructor.

Do note, `MouseEvent.CLICK` gets fired TWICE along with a `MouseEvent.DOUBLE_CLICK` event.